# Codelobster debugger not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, debugging

I am facing difficulty in attaching a debugger to a CodeIgniter framework in Codelobster. I am getting redirected to my desired page without stopping at the breakpoint. Please, can anyone tell what can be wrong?

[image: Codelobster debugging settings]

[image: Dlls]

Above dlls are copied in C:\xampp\php\ext

Also, in php.ini file below lines are present.

```
[CLDbg]
extension=php_cl_dbg_7_0_VC14_x64.dll
clport=6000
```

Comment: You web server is empty. Set to apache

Comment: Apache 2.0 or Apache 2.2?

Comment: After adding Apache 2.4 I am getting following error. [Tue Jul 12 22:38:00.059732 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 20236:tid 460] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Jul 12 22:38:00.445832 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 20236:tid 460] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Jul 12 22:38:00.524860 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 20236:tid 460] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

Comment: Also, web server field goes blank when I reopen the debugger tab

Comment: Hello ... Have you that problem solved? have a nearly identical problem using Codelobster ans Nova-framework.

Comment: @ratmalwer: No, I created a log file in my application and try to catch and solve the exceptions.

Comment: @Himani I reported the problem to the Codelobster-team. Now I received a new set of DLLs and it works fine with PHP7.0. Perhaps meanwhile there is an update at Codelobsters...

Comment: Thanks a ton @ratmalwer. Yeah, I am yet to update it. Please can you share those DLL's?

Comment: @Himani  can you give me a hint where to put it easyli? Got a email? I am not good in this kind of things

Comment: Are you asking to put the DLL?